# tomcat 7 unable to listen port 8080 with iptables enabled

Tags: tomcat, centos

We recently configured CentOS 6 with tomcat 7. We enabled the iptables as well as added the rules to accept port 80 and 8080. Selinux is enforcing.
We are able to access the application with 80 but 8080 is not listening at all. When we stop the iptables then the applications are accessible via 8080 as well.

Any idea what could be the cause for this?

Command used to add 8080 rule to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

UPDATE:
Resolved this issue by placing the above entry before "reject-with icmp-host-prohibited " rule in iptables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

And check the listening port with telnet:

telnet ***Server_IP_Address*** 8080

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could able to resolve this by adding this entry before to the rule with "reject-with icmp-host-prohibited" in the iptables.